# How to stop and resume all processes by one process in MPI?

Tags: c++, linux, mpi

In MPI what is the correct way that at a specific moment, one process (I call it process A) stops all processes doing the application tasks and then that process A resumes all? For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
   {
      int num_procs, my_rank, my_id;
      
      MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
      MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
      MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);
      
      my_id = getpid();
      printf("Hello! I'm process with rank %i out of %i processes and my id is %i\n", 
         my_rank, num_procs, my_id);

      // here I want process A stops all processes
      // ....

      usleep(3000000);    // sleep for 3 seconds

      // here I want that process A resumes all processes

      printf("Bye! I'm process %i out of %i processes and my id is %i\n", 
         my_rank, num_procs, my_id);

      
      MPI_Finalize();
      return 0;
   }
```

I tried using `kill(pid, SIGSTOP);` and `kill(pid, SIGCONT);` but the problem is that the id of each process obtained through `getpid()` is required so that that process A can use those ids to stop and resume the processes. I tried to see if I can obtain the processes ids and then one process can access them. So, I modified the above code as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> ids {};
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
   {
      int num_procs, my_rank;
      ids.push_back(getpid());
      
      MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
      MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
      MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);
      
      if (my_rank == 0){
         for (const int& i : ids) {
             std::cout << i << "\n";
         }
      }

      MPI_Finalize();
      return 0;
   }
```

But due to the parallelism of processes, it didn't work and `for` loop only prints out the id of the process with rank 0.

To rephrase my question, is there any way in MPI to stop and resumes processes?

**UPDATE**

Since I was asked in the comments why I need to do so, I add more explanations here. I intend to implement a coordinated checkpointing approach. It works as follows. One process as a coordinator at a specific time stops other processes from executing the main program tasks. Then each process takes its checkpoint and subsequently informs the coordinator process that checkpointing is done. When all processes finish taking their checkpoints, the coordinator resumes the other processes to carry on executing the main program tasks. The coordinator process can be one of the processes that execute the main program, and at checkpointing time, it also takes its checkpoint.

Comment: 1. Why? 2. Since you seem to know where you want to stop, why doesn't everyone sleep? 3. Alternatively, let everyone do an `MPI_Bcast` and process zero waits 3 seconds before it does the send.

Comment: MPI stands for Message Passing Interface. If you are looking at an event based distributed framework, this is not a good fit. You might have more luck with ZeroMQ.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but wouldn't a call to `MPI_Barrier` suffice here? Or is @GillesGouaillardet's answer more on point here? (Personally never worked with ZeroMQ)

Comment: `MPI_Barrier()` suggests all the processes but `A` enter the barrier, and then "wait" for A. The wording "I want A process stops all processes" suggests otherwise (at least in my interpretation).

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I added more explanation to the question under **UPDATE**.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I added more explanation to the question under **UPDATE**.

Comment: @BTM I added more explanation to the question under **UPDATE**.

Comment: To checkpoint (or more precisely, to resume from a checkpoint) easily one really wants to suspend activity at a given *state*, have all processes write their checkpoints, then carry on computing.  One doesn't want to suspend activity at a specified *time* at which the computation might be in any state at all. Resuming from a time-determined checkpoint requires resuming from almost any state of the computation.  Go for the `mpi_barrier` suggested by @BTM.

Comment: I agree with @HighPerformanceMark that you're fundamentally on the wrong track. Your mental image of MPI processes as synchronized is flawed. For checkpointing you need to synchronize on state, for which any number of MPI collectives will do the trick.